# format character length/limit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I would like to have a custom string that is truncated after exceeding a given length and has an indicator showing that it has been shortened for example: "a very long string" to " a very l...". Thanks in advance

Comment: Just discovered jQuery slice(). Does the trick

Comment: Doubt jQuery's `slice` does the trick tho, that's for jQuery collections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regex, where `10` is the number of characters you want to have.

```
str = str.replace(/(.{10}).*/, '$1...');
```

It can be abstracted like:

```
function truncate(str, len) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp('(.{'+ len +'}).*'), '$1...');
}

var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur';
console.log(truncate(str,10)); //=> "Lorem ipsu..."
```

Comment: Simplicity is king. This solution is a bit difficult to understand for beginners. Anyway, it's brilliant (+1)

Answer (score 2):

```
function truncateString(value, maxLength){
      var returnedValue = value;
      if (returnedValue.length > maxLength){
          returnedValue = returnedValue.substring(0,maxLength) + "...";
      }
      return returnedValue;
}
```

Comment: This is simple. Regex looks scary

Comment: @Remi Adeoye: yes, simplicity is king I think (KISS principle). However, you may choose the regex approach if you like it

Comment: Yeah, I agree, this is more beginner friendly. Regex seem scary but they're very quick to learn and I can assure you won't regret it.

Comment: @elclanrs: yes, I like the regex approach, really.

Comment: @RemiAdeoye: although the regex approach is brilliant. But in this case, I think we should use a simple approach. Because we work in a team, we cannot expect everybody to be able to understand it immediately, somebody may need to spend time to understand it. Simple approach is more common for everyone to understand and maintain the code.